# Does flutter application support sso using microsoft intune?

Tags: flutter, single-sign-on, intune

I need to implement SSO for a flutter application. 
Does flutter application support single sign on using microsoft intune ?

Comment: Please take a look at the question guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask StackOverflow is not a manual search engine.